Calculating average value by grouping by multiple variables using Group_by function in R studio
I have a table set up like this



Site
Replicate
Species
Value A




A
A
A
1


A
A
B
2


A
B
A
3


B
A
A
3


B
A
B
4


B
B
B
6


B
B
C
2


C
A
A
5


C
A
B
6



And I want to calculate the average of value A according to every site and species combination.
I have tried using the group_by function from the dplyr package with this code:
mean_valueA=invertebrates%>%
  group_by(site, species) %>%
  summarize(mean_val=mean(value A))

but it only seems to group by site without taking into consideration the species. Also, the number is the same for every grouping. Is there any way to solve this issue?
Thanks for your help!

I figured it out! I was writing my code as:
mean_valueA=df%>%
    group_by(df$site, df$species)
    summarize(mean_val=mean(df$ValueA)

because I thought that was the same as writing
mean_ValueA=df%>%
    group_by(site, species)
    summarize(mean_val=mean(valueA)

but it's not. By referencing my dataframe every time, I was creating these issues. I should just have referenced the column by themselves.
This post helped me a lot: Summarising giving same value for each group
